# Check cell = 0 if it does display message box and cancel save

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with some VBA code which seems so basic but yet is just not working. I am new to VBA so possible that I am missing something.

The code is supposed to check a cell (XFD3002) to see if it equals 0, if it does then display a message and stop the file from saving. For background, there is a check to see that certain cells are filled and if not it will return a 0.

The code is:

```
Private Sub Check_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim check As Integer
check = Sheets("Data").Range("XFD3002").Value

If check = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("You have missed one or more required field")
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone see something wrong with the above?

Comment: Cell value can be anything, not just integer, so it is not a good idea to use an integer variable to store it. Go with String. If you are sure only numbers between ~-32000 and ~+32000 will be in said cell, then go with @clusks's answer, and remove the quotes.

Comment: The cell value will always be an integer, so have declared it as that and now removed the quotes

Comment: Define "not working". Error messafe? False positive? Flase negative? Have you tried stepping through the code (F8)? Did you check what was in your `check` variable (Locals window, or mouse over it while you step through the code)?

Comment: shouldn't this be Workbook_BeforeSave ?

Comment: @Pierre this has fixed the issue, thank you very much

Comment: hahaha that was simple. :D  Should I put it as an answer so you accept it to close the question?

Comment: @Pierre Yes please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sub name should be `Workbook_BeforeSave`.

The hardest to find errors are always the simplest ones. :D

Answer (score -1):

You're seeing if what is in the check cell is a string, since you've put quotation marks around it - "0", but check has been declared as an integer. Try changing it to just 0 without the quotation marks.

EDIT: Please also ensure that this code appears in "TheWorkbook" module and change the name to Workbook_BeforeSave (as pointed out by @Pierre)

Comment: Just tried this but still not working for some reason.

Comment: Anything else you can see?

Comment: Where is the code? Have you put this in "TheWorkbook" in the Microsoft Excel Objects list?